# Date-FNS Timezone Abbreviation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns, date-fns-tz

How do I convert the Australian Eastern Daylight Time to just AEST?
Currently it outputs like `11/11/2022 15:29:25 Australian Eastern Daylight Time`.
Expected output would be like `11/11/2022 15:29:25 AEDT`

```
import { formatInTimeZone } from 'date-fns-tz'
import auLocale from 'date-fns/locale/en-AU'

formatInTimeZone(
        new Date(value),
        'Australia/Sydney',
        'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz',
        { locale: auLocale }
      )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zzz` for the format of the timezone instead of `zzzz`.

**Sample**: `'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz'`